# Sum of key values in list of dictionary grouped by particular key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to sum the values of keys grouped by scope

```
[
    {'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 1000, 'initial_boq': 2800}
    {'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 2000, 'initial_boq': 1000}    
    {'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 2000, 'initial_boq': 500}
    {'scope': u'external', 'invoiced': 500,  'initial_boq': 1800}
    {'scope': u'external', 'invoiced': 150,  'initial_boq': 200}
    {'scope': u'both',     'invoiced': 5000, 'initial_boq': 7000}
]
```

How we can get the sum of keys in dict grouping the scope eg:

Expected Output

```
[ 
   {'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 5000, 'initial_boq': 4300}, 
   {'scope': u'external', 'invoiced': 650, 'initial_boq': 2000},
   {'scope': u'both', 'invoiced': 5000, 'initial_boq': 7000} 
]
```

Kindly let me know how we can achieve the same

Comment: What do your previous attempts to solve this look like?

Comment: You probably want pandas for this kind of operation. You can do it with regular code but this is what pandas is for.

Comment: @PaulRooney [
    {'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 5000, 'initial_boq': 4300}
    {'scope': u'external', 'invoiced': 650,  'initial_boq': 2000}
    {'scope': u'both',     'invoiced': 5000, 'initial_boq': 7000}
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = [
    {'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 1000, 'initial_boq': 2800},
    {'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 2000, 'initial_boq': 1000},   
    {'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 2000, 'initial_boq': 500},
    {'scope': u'external', 'invoiced': 500,  'initial_boq': 1800},
    {'scope': u'external', 'invoiced': 150,  'initial_boq': 200},
    {'scope': u'both',     'invoiced': 5000, 'initial_boq': 7000}
]
tempJson = {}
finalList = []

for eachScopeJson in list1:
    if eachScopeJson['scope'] in tempJson:
        tempJson[eachScopeJson['scope']]['invoiced'] = tempJson[eachScopeJson['scope']]['invoiced'] + eachScopeJson['invoiced']
        tempJson[eachScopeJson['scope']]['initial_boq'] = tempJson[eachScopeJson['scope']]['initial_boq'] + eachScopeJson['initial_boq']
    else:
        tempJson[eachScopeJson['scope']] = {}
        tempJson[eachScopeJson['scope']]['invoiced'] = 0 + eachScopeJson['invoiced']
        tempJson[eachScopeJson['scope']]['initial_boq'] = 0 + eachScopeJson['initial_boq']


for eachKey in tempJson:
    finalList.append({'scope':eachKey,'invoiced':tempJson[eachKey]['invoiced'],'initial_boq':tempJson[eachKey]['initial_boq']})


print tempJson
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don’t provide anything about your previous attempts I’m assuming this question is about where to start.

First thing I’d look for is a data structure that makes solving your problem simple. In this case I’d create a dictionary of sums:

```py
sums = {
  'internal': {'invoiced': …, 'initial_boq': …},
  # …
}
```

Especially suited for this would be a defaultdict:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

sums = defaultdict(lamdba: defaultdict(lambda:0))
```

With this definition you can add your values like this:

```py
sums['internal']['invoiced'] += one_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`, like so. With an extra function to sum up the grouped items.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


d = [
    {'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 1000, 'initial_boq': 2800},
    {'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 2000, 'initial_boq': 1000}, 
    {'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 2000, 'initial_boq': 500},
    {'scope': u'external', 'invoiced': 500,  'initial_boq': 1800},
    {'scope': u'external', 'invoiced': 150,  'initial_boq': 200},
    {'scope': u'both',     'invoiced': 5000, 'initial_boq': 7000},
]


def getsummed(scope, elems):

    d = {'scope': scope, 'invoiced': 0, 'initial_boq': 0}

    for e in elems:
        d['invoiced'] += e['invoiced']
        d['initial_boq'] += e['initial_boq']
    return d


def sortedgroupby(iterable, key):

    return groupby(sorted(iterable, key=key), key=key)


print([getsummed(gpr, groups) for gpr, groups in sortedgroupby(d, key=itemgetter('scope'))])
```

result is

```
[{'scope': 'internal', 'invoiced': 5000, 'initial_boq': 4300}, {'scope': 'external', 'invoiced': 650, 'initial_boq': 2000}, {'scope': 'both', 'invoiced': 5000, 'initial_boq': 7000}]
```

Comment: It worked partially, I don't know why it gave the output in two dict for the same key i.e scope. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: It's probably because the list of elements isn't sorted by the `scope` property. It is in your example code. It would work if the input to `groupby` was sorted first. It becomes a bit unwieldy with code like `groupby(sorted(d, key=itemgetter('scope')), key=itemgetter('scope')`. So probably a custom grouping function is best.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner :)

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

key = lambda d: d['scope']
res = [dict(sum((Counter({k:v for k,v in grp.items() if k!='scope'}) for grp in grps), Counter()), scope=scope) for scope,grps in groupby(sorted(lst, key=key), key=key)]
print (res)

[{'invoiced': 5000, 'initial_boq': 7000, 'scope': 'both'}, {'invoiced': 650, 'initial_boq': 2000, 'scope': 'external'}, {'invoiced': 5000, 'initial_boq': 4300, 'scope': 'internal'}]
```

And here is the equivalent code for the that one-liner

```
key = lambda d: d['scope']
res = []
for scope,grps in groupby(sorted(lst, key=key), key=key):
    c = Counter()
    for grp in grps:
         grp.pop('scope')
         c += Counter(grp)

    res.append(dict(c, scope=scope))

pprint(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Much less spectacular than many solutions already posted here but very clear

```
def removeDuplicatedScopesFrom(startingData): 
    differentScopes = [] 
    for x in startingData:
        scope = x["scope"]
        if scope not in differentScopes: 
            differentScopes.append(scope) 
    return differentScopes
    
def composeDictionaryElement(scope, invoiced, initial_boq):
    return("{'scope': u'" + scope + "', 'invoiced': " + str(invoiced) + ", 'initial_boq': " + str(initial_boq) + "}")

def main():
    var = [
        {'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 1000, 'initial_boq': 2800},
        {'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 2000, 'initial_boq': 1000},   
        {'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 2000, 'initial_boq': 500},
        {'scope': u'external', 'invoiced': 500,  'initial_boq': 1800},
        {'scope': u'external', 'invoiced': 150,  'initial_boq': 200},
        {'scope': u'both',     'invoiced': 5000, 'initial_boq': 7000}
    ]
    
    # empty list for the final result
    finalList = []
    # identifying the different scopes involved
    scopes = removeDuplicatedScopesFrom(var)
    
    # scanning the input and joining data from the same scope
    for scope in scopes:
        
        # resetting values for each different scope
        invoiced = 0;
        initial_boq = 0;
        
        # checking all the elements in the list
        for y in var:
            if y["scope"] == scope:
                invoiced = invoiced + y["invoiced"]
                initial_boq = initial_boq + y["initial_boq"]
                
        # when list is over we ask to compose the related dictionary element
        finalDictionaryElement = composeDictionaryElement(scope, invoiced, initial_boq)
        # adding it to the final list
        finalList.append(finalDictionaryElement)
    
    # results out without surrounding quotes
    print("[%s]" % (', '.join(finalList)))
    
if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Output

```
[{'scope': u'internal', 'invoiced': 5000, 'initial_boq': 4300}, {'scope': u'external', 'invoiced': 650, 'initial_boq': 2000}, {'scope': u'both', 'invoiced': 5000, 'initial_boq': 7000}]
```